# How to toggle a std_logic between 1 and 0

Tags: vhdl

I want to toggle a std_logic vector '1' and '0' everytime the input sel='1'.
I tried this with the following method but both lines give an error.

```
selected <= not selected when sel='1';
```

> ERROR: This construct is only supported in VHDL 1076-2008

```
selected <= ~selected when sel='1';
```

> ERROR: Syntax error near "~"

Is there a better way to toggle, or what is the right syntax for a 'not' function.

Here is the code for the entire architecture:

```
architecture Behavioral of selWeerg is

signal selected : std_logic;

begin   
process(sel,digl,sysclk)
begin
    if rising_edge(sysclk) then

        selected <= ~selected when sel='1';

        if selected = '0' then
            digO1<=digl(3 downto 0);
        else
            digO2<=digl(3 downto 0);
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You cannot read a signal in the same process as you assign to it. You need to separate the code that toggles selected into a different process to the code that tests it.

Comment: `~` is not an operator in VHDL. You need `not`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you it doesn't work: the code you are writing is only supported in VHDL-2008, not in previous versions. In previous versions, it is illegal to use the `when`-`else` construct inside a process. Why? Who knows? Which is probably why it was made legal in VHDL-2008.

So, you either need to enable VHDL-2008 compilation on your simulator or use an `if` statement instead. Using VHDL-2008 is not a decision to be taken lightly, because many tools don't understand it.

Comment: Why? Because it's not Ada, I imagine - you're back-porting the new concurrent stuff into the old Ada-like sequential stuff. Ada 2012 introduced a new sort-of-similar ternary.